# Find element in set from reading file line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the text file with delimiter `|`: file1.txt

```
ID|Name|Date
1|A|2017-12-19   
2|B|2017-12-20
3|C|2017-12-21
```

And following `SET`: `<type 'set'>`

```
id_set = set(['1','2'])
date_set = set(['2017-12-19', '2017-12-20'])
```

I just want to find the matching element from set to file and write that record from file1.txt to output.txt.

Expected Output: `Output.txt` should get following data,

```
ID|Name|Date
1|A|2017-12-19   
2|B|2017-12-20
```

Comment: If `id_set = {1}` and `date_set = set()`, would the output be `1|A|2017-12-19` or an empty file?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, The output will be `1|A|2017-12-19`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out this solution:

```
id_set = {'1','2'}
date_set = {'2017-12-19', '2017-12-20'}

# open files for reading and writing
with open('file.txt') as in_file, open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:

    # write headers
    out_file.write(next(in_file))

    # go over lines in file
    for line in in_file:

        # extract id and date
        id, _, date = line.rstrip().split('|')

        # keep lines have an id or date in the sets
        if id in id_set or date in date_set:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Which gives the following *output.txt*:

```
ID|Name|Date
1|A|2017-12-19
2|B|2017-12-20
```

Comment: From the OP's comment responding to Aran-Fey, it looks like they're looking for an `or`, not an `and` here. (Also, you're missing at least one `#`, so this code is a SyntaxError as posted…)

Comment: @abarnert Cheers, missed that completely for some reason. Fixed the code to be more sensible now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""ID|Name|Date
1|A|2017-12-19
2|B|2017-12-20
3|C|2017-12-21""")

# replace mystr with 'file1.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, sep='|')

# criteria
id_set = {'1', '2'}
date_set = {'2017-12-19', '2017-12-20'}

# apply criteria
df2 = df[df['ID'].astype(str).isin(id_set) | df['Date'].isin(date_set)]

print(df2)

#   ID Name        Date
# 0  1    A  2017-12-19
# 1  2    B  2017-12-20

# export to csv
df2.to_csv('file1_out.txt', sep='|')
```